# Data insertion problem in sqlite

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, ipad, sqlite

My table definition  is: CREATE TABLE "Product" ("ProID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL , "BarCode" VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE , "ProductName" VARCHAR NOT NULL );

when i am inserting data i have the problem like: 
2011-03-25 15:43:08.792 BarCode12[6698:207] *** Assertion failure in -[sqlClass addRecord:], /Users/admin/Desktop/BarCode14copy/Classes/sqlClass.m:121
2011-03-25 15:43:08.793 BarCode12[6698:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while inserting data. 'constraint failed''
...

The code written is:  - (void) addRecord:(NSMutableDictionary *)recordDict
{

```
if(addStmt == nil) {
    const char *sql = "insert into Product(ProID, BarCode , ProductName ) Values(?,?,?)";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
NSInteger recordId =  [[recordDict objectForKey:@"ProID"] intValue];
NSLog(@"%d",recordId);
sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 1,recordId);
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [[recordDict objectForKey:@"BarCode"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [[recordDict objectForKey:@"ProductName"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
else
    sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
    rowID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
NSLog(@"last inserted rowId = %d",rowID);

sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
```

}

i am also tried without constraints but the same problem will continues..

if the consistency is removed then it shows "database Locked" error..
how can we remove this error and how to insert the data into database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bit about "constraint failed" says that you are violating a constraint.  That means your `Product` table has PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE or FOREIGN KEY constraints, and that you’re inserting values which would violate those constraints.

- For PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE constraints: you’re inserting a duplicate value.
- For FOREIGN KEY constraints: you’re inserting a value that has no corresponding match in the referenced table/field.

**Update**: When you have an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, then you shouldn’t specify a ProdID in your INSERT statement; SQLite will generate it automatically.  So change your insert statement to

```
INSERT INTO Product (BarCode , ProductName) Values (?,?)
```

since your already retrieve it afterward with

```
rowID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
```

Don’t forget to remove the binding, too!

Comment: thank you, i am using PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE constraints but i am not inserting duplicate values..

Comment: SQLite says that you are, and it tends to be right about these things.  Do you have any triggers associated with your table?

Comment: i am using one as primary key and another as Unique both are separately is it problem?

Comment: No, that shouldn’t be the problem. Could you post the table’s definition in your question?

Comment: CREATE TABLE "Product" ("ProID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "BarCode" VARCHAR NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "ProductName" VARCHAR NOT NULL )

Comment: this is my table defination sir,

Comment: (I meant `edit` your question, and add the table definition there, instead of here in the comments to my answer).